# Sign of the functional equation of L function and Shimura lift

Tags: automorphic-forms, l-functions, half-integral-weight

I would like to know what happens to the root number of a half integral weight automorphic form (holomorphic or not), i.e. the sign of the functional equation of its L-function when we apply the Shimura lift.

Does it stay the same, get reversed, or something more complicated? How would these signs be distributed if you ran along Maass forms of weight 1/2?